# Motion Graphics tag missing

Tags: discussion

Yesterday when I asked a question regarding **motion graphics**, I used the tag `motion` believing it's for that. But later found that it's primarily for **Motion software by Apple**.

Why there is no ***motion graphics*** tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No particular reason.  I think most of the time people have used either animation or the particular software being used, but motion-graphics probably does make sense as a tag.